# "others", pronoun or determiner

Tags: pronouns, determiners

> You shouldn’t expect **others** to do your work for you.

Does "others" function as *pronoun* in the above sentence and replaced the *noun* (e.g. people)? or Is it determiner and the *noun/pronoun* (e.g. people) has been omitted?

> - determiner: You shouldn’t expect **<strike>others</strike> other people** to do your work for you.
> - pronoun: You shouldn’t expect **people** to do your work for you.

Comment: In your first example, "others" is a common noun that is interpreted as "other people". In "other people" it is an adjective modifying "people".

Answer (score 1):

Dictionaries I checked list "other" as a pronoun in that usage, so that is most clearly the right answer.

However, I believe your intuition is correct that "others" began as a determiner ("**other** people" - note the singular, never plural here) with the noun dropped as it is obvious in context. You could try asking at [linguistics](http://linguistics.stackexchange.com) for more.

Comment: Most dictionaries I have checked list this kind of other as a noun not a pronoun. [Scroll down here to see  "other" noun definition 2](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/other)

Comment: In _You shouldn’t expect others to do your work for you_."other" can only be a noun because it has the plural form "others". Pronouns don't have plural forms. It's an adjective of course in "other people".

Comment: @BillJ Of course pronouns have plural forms. What are you talking about?

Comment: What I meant was that "other" inflects for number, with "others" as the plural form. And it differs from pronouns in that it takes determiners, e.g. _the three others_. It has a count interpretation, and unlike pronouns it has an antecedent that is not a full NP. In this use, "other" is syntactically a common noun, not a pronoun. Now do you understand?

Comment: @BillJ, when you say "the three others" I believe that is a different usage than saying only "others" as a substitute for a noun phrase like "some other group of people." I'll point you to Araucaria's link above, definition #3 (pronoun used to mean a different one, and can be plural in construction.)

Comment: I don't think that's the case at all. In, for example, "She left us six pears; this one is riper than the others", "others" is interpreted anaphorically as "other pears". It's function is no different to the OP's example where "others" is understood as "other people" - it is a pro-form in both examples. Incidentally, the noun "other" is derived by conversion from the adjective "other".

Comment: The difference is when you say "the others", the definite article marks it as a noun.

Comment: The fact that "other" can take a determiner at all is sufficient evidence that it is a noun. There's no reason to say that the undetermined "others" in the OP's example should be assigned to a different category that the determined "others" in "You shouldn’t expect _the_ others to do your work for you. And as I said before, pronouns do not inflect for number like common count nouns do, and "others" is clearly the inflected plural form of "other". There is no evidence to support it being a pronoun.

Comment: The same word can be different parts of speech depending on usage. Just because you can use others as a noun doesn't make it always a noun. Why keep making up new examples when the evidence is right there, in the dictionary, under pronoun.

Answer (score 1):

The OED calls this usage a pronoun. Here's the whole taxonomy of the usage you cited, followed by one of the many examples there.

> **Entry:**  *other,* adj., pron., and n., and adv. *2*
>   
> **B.** pron. and n.
>   
> **I.** As pronoun.
>   
> **6.** Another person; someone else; anyone else.
>   
> **b.** With plural sense.
>   
> **(b)** In form others (also genitive plural others', formerly others.) (The regular modern form.)
>   
> 1962    E. Waugh *Diary* 5 Oct. (1976) 790    She can write, think and pray exclusively of **others**; dreams are all egocentric.

One reason we might posit for the analysis as a pronoun is that we are not thinking of an indefinite count noun "others", such that you could point to the specific others and count them and distinguish them from the particular "others" that someone else thinks of.<sup>1</sup> Instead, there is only one "others" that we all share, and it means "The set of people excluding the speaker."<sup>2</sup>

It does also have a common noun sense with various meanings; one good example is this:

> 1988    P. Brown *Body & Society* (1989) ii. 39    Slaves were the second inferior **other** in the world of the free male.

Meanwhile, it's clear that in your sentence it isn't a determiner nor an adjective. One reason is that neither category is inflected in English, hence *others* is not a possible form of the adjective *other*.

Whether the noun and pronoun grew out of the determiner sense or vice versa, or whether some kind of ellipsis always occurs as you propose in your question, is a more academic question. The OED has many senses of both the pronoun and the adjective going back to early Old English.

---

<sup>1 Of course, there is also another sense "the others", as in "You're the only one home? Where are the others?" This *does* refer to a particular group of people who could be identified and counted.</sup>

<sup>2 Technically this set picks out different entities for every speaker,
 but that doesn't make it any more a common noun than it does the phrase "everyone else".</sup>